# Fill series with irregular gaps in between

Tags: excel, vba

I have a set of data in which when there is value in column B then i need to fill corresponding column A with number series 1,2,3... Is this possible in VBA??

I filled the below formula in VBA but it will return 1 in all cases... while I need 1,2,3 etc.

```
Range("I22").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF((NOT(ISBLANK(RC27))),""1"","" "")"
```

Comment: @braX I have made the edit ..

Comment: But, your formula does exactly what you say it does. It writes "1" if the cell is not blank and " " it it is blank. Probably, you wanted to write "", which means nothing... Now, based on what would you like to increment the numbers? Based on the above cell value?

Comment: yes I need to increment .. based on the previous cell which has a value.

Comment: And the cell with formula and the "previous one" is it possible to not be consecutive?

Comment: @FaneDuru thanks mate. I got solution!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should also do the trick:

```
=IF(LEN($AA22),COUNTIF($AA$22:AA22,"<>"&""),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can paste the following formula in Column A. This will work.

```
=IF(B2="","",MAX($A$1:A1)+1)
```

Comment: guess there is some glitch!! its not working properly.. its returning 1, 2, 2, 3

Answer (score 1):

Try using `count` formula? You'd want a variable to store the location....

Copy and paste this:

```
Dim rng as range
rng = Range("I22")
rng.FormulaR1C1= "=IF(ISBLANK(RC27), """", COUNT(" & Range("A1").Address(True, True, xlR1C1) & ":RC27))"
```

Then replace `A1` with the top cell of the column you want to count, and `I22` with the cell that the formula goes in.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, please:

```
Range("I22").Formula = "=IF((NOT(ISBLANK($AA22))),IF(I21="""",1,I21+1),"""")"
```

It will increment the I21 value, if any. If nothing, it will write 1 (not "1"), like start of iteration...